# How to deduce template type if I only got pointer to base class

Tags: c++

How could I implement function `Foo` to dispatch to the correct function?

The following code reproduces the problem, and got some additional information in comments.

```
#include <string>

class Base  
{
public:
virtual ~Base(){};
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base 
{};

void DoSomething(const Derived<std::string> &){};
void DoSomething(const Derived<int> &){};

void Foo(Base *test)
{
    // How to call correct DoSomething method?
    // (I can't change class Base, but I know that test points to some instance of class Derived)?
    // if(test points to an instance of Derived<int>)
    //     call void DoSomething(const Derived<int> &){};
    // else if(test points to an instance of Derived<std::string>)
    //     call void DoSomething(const Derived<std::string> &){};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base *test = new Derived<int>;

    Foo(test);

    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The same as for non-templated base classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the OO, only the derived class itself knows who it is, and what to do.

```
#include <string>
class Base {}
class Mid : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Mid 
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() {}
};

template<> void Derived<std::string>::DoSomething(){}
template<> void Derived<int>::DoSomething(){}

void Foo(Base *test)
{
    dynamic_cast<Mid*>(test)->DoSomething(); //TODO check the return of dynamic_cast
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base *test = new Derived<int>;

    Foo(test);

    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @nabulke can you at least tell us whether the base class is polymorphic?

Comment: @nabulke How about add a class between `Base` and `Derived` ? `class Mid : public Base { virtual void DoSomething()=0; }; template<typename T> class Derived : public Mid {...}; void Foo(Base *test) { dynamic_cast<Mid*>(test)->DoSomething(); }`

Comment: With a `dynamic_cast` you need to check whether what's returned is null or not. If you don't need to check it (because you know the dynamic type due to context), you should use a `static_cast` instead.

Comment: @enobayram You are right, I need to check the return of `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 3):

```
void Foo(Base *test)
{
  if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(test))
    DoSomething(*p);
  else if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<Derived<string>*>(test))
    DoSomething(*p);
  else
    throw runtime_error("oops");
}
```

This works because dynamic_cast returns nullptr if the type is not correct.  The code above is C++11, but it would be C++98 if you replace the "auto" types with the obvious ones (I'd use a macro if there are lots of cases).

Comment: technically correct but obviously a design that could be drastically improved by using polymorphism

Comment: The OP said the Base class cannot be modified.  If you have a better solution, let's see it.  :)

Comment: @jrok: Yes, it does have that restriction and I should have mentioned it.  But we don't know if the OP's Base is polymorphic or not (I assume it's not an empty class as in the OP).

Comment: Can't we make `DoSomething()` a member of `Derived<T>` so we don't have to change `Foo(...)` when a new type is used for the template ?

Comment: I posted an answer. Could you give me your opinion about it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <string>

class Base  
{};

class DerivedBase : public Base 
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public DerivedBase
{};

void Foo(Base *test)
{
   if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<DerivedBase*>(test))
       p->DoSomething();
   else
       throw runtime_error("oops");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Base *test = new Derived<int>;

   Foo(test);

   delete test;
   return 0;
}
```

If you declare an intermediate class, you can use polymorphism without changing `Base`. You only have to do one `dynamic_cast<>` but you won't have to change `Foo()` each time you want to use a new type as a template argument, thus having your code respect the Open/Closed Principle.

Comment: I thought about this too--I think it depends on the greater context the OP is operating within, which we can't entirely visualize.  I can imagine some worlds where this would be a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How to call correct DoSomething method?

It's much better is take advantage of how polymorphism works in C++ rather than to write some dispatch function based on casting. A couple of alternatives:

- Declare `DoSomething` as a public pure virtual method in class `Base`. The template will provide the implementation.
- Define `DoSomething` as a public non-virtual method in class `Base`. The implementation invokes some private pure virtual method. The template once again provides the implementation of this virtual method.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change class Base.

Comment: It seems that `Base` class can't be modified

Comment: So make a class that derives from `Base` that you can change, and make your class templates derived from this intermediate class rather than directly from `Base`.